# Delphi 10, .NET, how do I convert a hex UTF-8 string to its unicode character?

Tags: delphi, unicode, utf-8, delphi-2006

I am trying to make my web app compatible with international languages and I am stuck with trying to convert escaped characters in my Delphi .NET DLL.

The front end code is passing the UTF-8 hex notation with an escape character e.g  for お I pass \uE3818A. In my DLL I capture this and constract the following string '$E3818A'. I need to convert this back to お and send it to my database, I've been trying to use Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes and Encoding.UTF8.GetString but with no luck.

Anyone could help me figure this out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call:

```
byte.Parse("12", NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

on every to characters and store into `byte[]`, then call `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteStr)`

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine for £, carriage return and German! I still can't get Japanese or Greek characters to work, but I will worry about that later. 

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Turn your string into a byte array representing the original bytes (in this case 0xE3, 0x81, 0x8A), and then call `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)` - that should be fine.